# Java Abstract Classes

Tags: java

1)Почему метод

```
public String getAuthor(){
    return "AAA";
}
```

ниже не работает в main?

2)Если 2 класс наследует абстрактный и в абстрактном классе есть переменная приватная. Я создаю несколько объектов такого класса(который не абстрактный), допустим 5. То создается и 5 приватных переменных, которые были в втором классе, от которого унаследовали первый класс?

```
/* ООП - книги
1. Создайте public static класс MarkTwainBook, который наследуется от Book.
     Имя автора [Mark Twain]. Параметр конструктора - имя книги.
2. В классе MarkTwainBook реализуйте все абстрактные методы.
3. Для метода getBook расширьте тип возвращаемого результата.
4. Создайте по аналогии AgathaChristieBook. Имя автора [Agatha Christie].
5. В классе Book реализуйте тело метода getOutputByBookType так, чтобы он возвращал:
5.1. agathaChristieOutput для книг Агаты Кристи;
5.2. markTwainOutput для книг Марка Твена.
*/
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class Solution {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Book> books = new LinkedList<Book>();
        books.add(new MarkTwainBook("Tom Sawyer"));
        books.add(new AgathaChristieBook("Hercule Poirot"));
        System.out.println(books);
    }

    public abstract static class Book {
        private String author;

        public Book(String author) {
            this.author = author;
        }

        public abstract Book getBook();

        public abstract String getName();

        private String getOutputByBookType() {
            String agathaChristieOutput = author + ", " + getBook().getName() + " is a detective";
            String markTwainOutput = getBook().getName() + " book was written by " + author;
            Book book = getBook();
            String output = "output";
            if(book instanceof AgathaChristieBook)
                output =  agathaChristieOutput;//Add your code here
            else
                output = markTwainOutput;
            return output;
        }

        public String toString() {
            return getOutputByBookType();
        }
    }
    public static class MarkTwainBook extends Book{

        private String nameBook;



 public String getAuthor(){
             return "AAA";
        }

        public MarkTwainBook(String nameBook) {
            super("Mark Twain");
            this.nameBook = nameBook;
        }

        @Override
        public MarkTwainBook getBook() {
            return (MarkTwainBook)this;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return nameBook;
        }
    }

    public static  class AgathaChristieBook extends Book{
        public String getAuthor(){
            return super.author;
        }
        private String nameBook;
        public AgathaChristieBook(String nameBook) {
            super("Agatha Christie");
            this.nameBook = nameBook;
        }

        @Override
        public AgathaChristieBook getBook() {
            return (AgathaChristieBook)this;
        }

        @Override
        public String getName() {
            return nameBook;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: наверное потому что в базовом типе не определен. Будет лучше, если вы напишете код, который у вас вызывает ошибку, чтоб нам не гадать, что значить "не работает". Еще можете привести текст учебного задания. Поскольку приведена попытка решения, вас за это вряд ли сильно заминусуют :)

Comment: Да, но странно. Почему я не могу выполнить код в новом классе, обязательно разве это делать в абстрактном классе?

Comment: покажите, как вы "не можете".

Comment: Прописываю а мэйне books.get(0).getAuthor(); , но красным подчёркивает getAuthor, мол, не такого метода

Comment: ну да, в `books` у вас лежат объекты типа `Book`, у типа `Book` нет метода `getAuthor`, компилятор негодует. Вот если бы у `Book` был `getAuthor()`, все бы скомпилировалось, а во время выполнения был бы вызван `getAuthor()` от класса реального объекта (`MarkTwainBook`), потому что полиморфизм. А идея создавать приватный метод в родительском класса, определять там `instanseof`ами свой реальный тип и что-то разное от этого делать - странная.

Comment: Это такое задание. Спасибо большое. А на второй вопрос ответить можете?

Answer (score 1):

Насчет второго вопроса. Да, создается пять `private` переменных, к которому доступ будет только у переменной типа класса `Book`. Доступ к полю класса в наследуемых классах может осуществлен с помощью метода определенного в super-классе, либо сделать модификатор доступа у переменной `protected`.